# Compiler does not support microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, codewarrior

I have a basic question. For microcontroller project , we need a compiler which support that specific microcontroller. But if compiler does not support a specific microcontroller then what does it mean?  In other words ''Compiler support this microcontroller '' what it means? Any detailed description will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Support" just means "work with".

Comment: @Mick Sharpe Would you please elaborate, how compiler support microcontroller? e.g. Compiler has some files which provides information about interal architecture of microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler transforms high level source code into lower level assembly instructions.  Different families of CPU cores use different assembly instruction sets.  For example,  the Intel x86 instruction set is different from the ARM instruction set.  A compiler that doesn't support a specific microcontroller cannot transform source code into that microcontroller's assembly instruction set.

Comment: Exactly right. But currently I am facing a problem that a compiler (Codewarrior) support MPC56xx family but it does not support MPC57xx Family. As both families are based on powerpc and have same instruction set. But then how codewarrior could not support next family? What could be the reasons?

Comment: Only NXP/Freescale can answer that. It looks as if the MPC57xx family is supported in S32 Design Studio so maybe they won't be updating Codewarrior to support new products. Just a guess.

Comment: Oh, so that was just a setup question for your real question?  SMH.  An IDE is more than just a compiler. And sometimes product requirements are market-driven. Ask the vendor.

Comment: @KKrambo my question is still the same that I want to ask. Above I just explained as an example where I got this question. I am still confused when a compiler is supporting a MCU series and how it become not supporting the nex MCU series. As both series have same instruction set. So I am looking for different factors , besides Instruction set , which could be  reasons for compiler to not support a microcontroller?

Comment: @waq either you don't have the lastest version, or the product *itself* is not being "supported" properly. Things don't always happen clean and quick out here.